# Why aren't my maths questions working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I go to run the program it repeats `"What is the answer?"`.

```
import random
def questions():
    name=input("What is your name: ")
    print("Hello there",name,"!")


    finish = False
    questionnumber = 0
    correctquestions = 0

    while finish == False:
        choice = random.choice("+-x")
        if questionnumber < 10 | questionnumber >= 0:
            number1 = random.randrange(1,10)
            number2 = random.randrange(1,10)
            print((number1),(choice),(number2))

            while True:
                try:
                    answer=int(input("What is the answer?"))
                except ValueError:
                    print("your answer must me a number!")
                    continue
            questionnumber = questionnumber + 1
            if choice==("+"):
                realanswer = number1+number2
            if answer==realanswer:
                print("That's the correct answer")
                correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
            else:
                print("Wrong answer, the answer was",realanswer,"!")

            if choice==("x"):
                realanswer = number1*number2
                if answer==realanswer:  
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",realanswer,"!")

            if choice==("-"):
                realanswer = number1-number2

                if answer==realanswer:
                    print("That's the correct answer")
                    correctquestions = correctquestions + 1
                else:
                    print("Wrong answer, the answer was",realanswer,"!")
        finish = True
        print("Good job",name,"! You have finished the quiz")
        print("You scored " + str(correctquestions) + "/10 questions.")
questions()
```

For example:

```
What is your name: Will
Hello there Will !
3 x 9
What is the answer?27
What is the answer?27
What is the answer?
```

Comment: `while True` will never break...

Comment: You would find it easier to debug if you split the program into small, self-contained functions. See also http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

That `continue` statement is useless: the loop's going to continue anyway. What you need there is a `break`, like this:

```
    while True:
        try:
            answer = int(input("What is the answer?"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Your answer must be a number!")
```

Also note that you have a typo in your error message: you have `me` instead of `be`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite `while` loop here:

```
while True:
    try:
        answer=int(input("What is the answer?"))
    except ValueError:
        print("your answer must me a number!")
        continue
```